# How to export an Multi Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

i am trying get the ***stationList*** but it's not working . please help me.

it showing error  :-

> **E_WARNING : type 2 -- Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

```
$output= '{"apiStatus": 
                 {"message":"SUCCESS","success":true},
           "stationList":
                 {"stationName":"10th.mile","stationId":-1}, 
                 {"stationName":"4 Th Mile Masjid","stationId":-1}
          }';

$json = json_decode($output, true);
$data =   $json['stationList']; 
$json1 = json_decode($data, true);
foreach($json1 as $r){

    echo $r['stationName'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: you `$output` is not correct json

Comment: stationsList in your json is not an array! did you post it correctly in your question?

Comment: check your json in json lint. https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your json should be like this

```
$output= '{
"apiStatus": {
        "message": "SUCCESS",
        "success": "true"
    },
    "stationList": [{
        "stationName": "10th.mile",
        "stationId": -1
    },
    {
        "stationName": "4 Th Mile Masjid",
        "stationId": -1
    }]
}';

  /*convert json into array*/
$json_arr = json_decode($output, true); 
/*get  station list*/
$data_station = $json_arr['stationList'];
foreach($data_station as $r){

    echo $r['stationName'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: please check my answer @Dillip

Comment: please upvote my answer if  my answer solved your problem @Dillip